# Magento 2 xml validation

Tags: magento2, xml, validation

For a while Magento 2 had a way to validate (and autocomplete) any xml by using an XSD file.
For example`module.xml` looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    ....
</config>
```

but now `module.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    ....
</config>
```

so  the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute contains `urn:magento:framework:`.

I know that this has nothing to do with the server side validation of the xmls. This one still works.
But what can I do to get back my validation in my IDE (PHPStorm in my case, but that's not important, it can be anything else) in order to recognize the path to the xsd?
Should I still use the old relative path while building my modules? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: http://alankent.me/2015/10/07/xml-schema-resolution-in-php-storm-with-urns-quick-note/ - I think this should help?

Comment: @Marius, I could not see the answer of "Should I still use the old relative path while building my modules? Or is there a better way of doing it?"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Check updates to the GitHub today, Magento 2 introduced new command to automatically generate all the URN resolutions for the PhpStorm.

To use it:

- have Magento installed on the same machine as PhpStorm
- go to the root directory
- execute command `bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml` where `.idea/misc.xml` is path to your PhpStorm misc.xml file

All of the URNs should be magically resolved now!

Check them under  `PhpStorm->Preferences -> Languages&Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs`

PhpStorm 9.0 (windows) : `File -> Settings -> Languages&Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs`

Note: Make sure your path to the magento2 installation in phpstorm is the same, or update the paths in the misc.xml file.

- restart phpstorm

Comment: If Phpstorm isn't in the same machine as the code, I think it's still safe to copy that file somewhere near magento code, execute the command provided, and then copy back to dev environnement.

Comment: There is some magic file naming for PHP Storm. The file HAS to be named misc.xml in the .idea directory

Answer (score 12):

So magento changed the XSD URI to use Urns - These need to be configured in PHP Storm in order for schema validation to work again.

Source : http://alankent.me/2015/10/07/xml-schema-resolution-in-php-storm-with-urns-quick-note/

The URN resolution code is built into Magento directly. Luckily, it’s pretty easy to associate URNs with real files in your local site in PHP Strom.

This is what you will see after loading a newever magento2 version with urns. Notice the URN is in red because PHP Storm does not know how to resolve it.

[image]

Put the cursor in the URN then click on the red light bulb to the left that will appear and select “Manually Setup External Resource” from the list.

[image]

Scroll down the list of XSD files that PHP Storm has automatically located, and select the appropriate file. The red URN will now be shown in green, and XML validation is back in effect.

Answer (score 8):

URN generation is supported by [Magento 2 plugin](https://github.com/dkvashninbay/magento2plugin) for PHP Storm, and is only one of many useful features it provides to Magento 2 developers.

When plugin is installed in the PHP Storm, go to `Preferences / Other Settings / Magento2 plugin`  and click `Regenerate URN map`.

Comment: Link to plugin no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

## Eclipse IDE Users:

*(Updated July 11th 2019 for Magento 2.3.1)*

**Pros:**

- Eclipse will recognize the path to the XSDs, and all the benefits which that brings.

**Cons:**

- Configuration is at a workspace scope, not project scope.
- Manually have to set it up.
- If Magento adds new XSDs in future versions, or changes the path, you'll have to manually manage these changes.

## Instructions:

- Using your preferred file manager, navigate to the root of your Eclipse's workspace directory. If on linux, and you're just using the default workspace location, it is most likely `~/workspace`.
- In your eclipse workspace directory find `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core/user_catalog.xml` (if does not exist, create it)
- Paste the contents below and replace "ROOT" with your actual path:

Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-webapi/etc/webapi.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/etc/mview.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-cron/etc/crontab.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/address_formats.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/address_formats.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-store/etc/config.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Event/etc/events.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Validator/etc/validation.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/etc/validation.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/etc/cache.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-email/etc/email_templates.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/etc/routes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/menu.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-config/etc/system_file.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/sections.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_types.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_types.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/catalog_attributes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/sales.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf_file.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-widget/etc/widget.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/resources.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/etc/resources.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Config/etc/view.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-cron/etc/cron_groups.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_WebapiAsync:etc/webapi_async.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-webapi-async/etc/webapi_async.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Eav:etc/eav_attributes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-eav/etc/eav_attributes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_options.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_options.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types_merged.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types_merged.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_options_merged.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_options_merged.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Directory:etc/zip_codes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/zip_codes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/data_source.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/data_source.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Integration:etc/integration/integration.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-integration/etc/integration/integration.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_definition.map.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/ui_definition.map.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_definition.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/ui_definition.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Config/etc/theme.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-payment/etc/payment.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/import.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import_merged.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/import_merged.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/export_merged.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/export_merged.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/export.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-import-export/etc/export.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_request.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Search/etc/search_request.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_engine.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Search/etc/search_engine.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Analytics:etc/analytics.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-analytics/etc/analytics.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Analytics:etc/reports.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-analytics/etc/reports.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Paypal:etc/rules.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-paypal/etc/rules.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_include.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-config/etc/system_include.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Logging:etc/logging.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-logging/etc/logging.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/menu_section.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/etc/menu_section.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/etc/content_type.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_WebsiteRestriction:etc/webrestrictions.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-website-restriction/etc/webrestrictions.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:/App/etc/routes.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework//App/etc/routes.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Elasticsearch:etc/esconfig.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/etc/esconfig.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Logging:etc/logging_file.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-logging/etc/logging_file.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_GiftRegistry:etc/giftregistry.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry/etc/giftregistry.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/error_mapping.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-payment/etc/error_mapping.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Klarna_Core:etc/klarna.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/klarna/module-core/etc/klarna.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_VersionsCms:etc/menu_hierarchy.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/etc/menu_hierarchy.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Signifyd:etc/signifyd_payment_mapping.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-signifyd/etc/signifyd_payment_mapping.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/topology.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/etc/topology.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/etc/consumer.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-foreign-key:etc/constraints.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-foreign-key/etc/constraints.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_AdminGws:etc/admingws.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-admin-gws/etc/admingws.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Persistent:etc/persistent.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-persistent/etc/persistent.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/publisher.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/etc/publisher.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/queue.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/etc/queue.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/etc/communication.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Support:etc/report.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-support/etc/report.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types_base.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types_base.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Integration:etc/integration/integration_base.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-integration/etc/integration/integration_base.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_component.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_component.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/action.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/action.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actionDelete.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actionDelete.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actions.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actions.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actionsColumn.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/actionsColumn.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/bookmark.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/bookmark.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/boolean.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/boolean.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/button.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/button.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/checkbox.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/checkbox.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/checkboxset.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/checkboxset.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/colorPicker.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/colorPicker.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/column.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/column.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/columns.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/columns.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/columnsControls.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/columnsControls.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/component.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/component.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/container.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/container.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dataSource.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dataSource.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/date.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/date.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dynamicRows.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dynamicRows.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/email.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/email.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/exportButton.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/exportButton.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/field.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/field.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/urlInput.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/urlInput.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/fieldset.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/fieldset.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/file.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/file.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/fileUploader.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/fileUploader.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/filterRange.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/filterRange.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/filters.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/filters.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/form.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/form.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/hidden.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/hidden.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/htmlContent.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/htmlContent.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/imageUploader.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/imageUploader.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/input.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/input.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/insertForm.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/insertForm.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/insertListing.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/insertListing.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/listing.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/listing.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/massaction.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/massaction.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/modal.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/modal.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/multiline.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/multiline.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/multiselect.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/multiselect.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/nav.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/nav.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/number.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/number.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/paging.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/paging.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/price.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/price.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/radioset.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/radioset.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/select.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/select.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/selectionsColumn.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/selectionsColumn.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/tab.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/tab.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/text.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/text.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/textarea.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/textarea.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/wysiwyg.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/wysiwyg.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/inlineEditing.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/inlineEditing.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/listingToolbar.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/listingToolbar.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dataProvider.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/dataProvider.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_components.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/etc/ui_components.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Data/etc/argument/types.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Data/etc/argument/types.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_settings.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_settings.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/types.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/module-widget/etc/types.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/head.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/head.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/body.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/body.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/html.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/html.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/requests.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Search/etc/requests.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/name.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/name.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/decimal.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/decimal.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/float.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/float.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/double.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/real/double.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/integer.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/integer.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/biginteger.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/biginteger.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/smallinteger.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/smallinteger.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/tinyinteger.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/integers/tinyinteger.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/text.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/text.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/longtext.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/longtext.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/mediumtext.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/mediumtext.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/varchar.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/varchar.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/blob.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/blob.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/mediumblob.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/mediumblob.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/longblob.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/longblob.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/varbinary.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/varbinary.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/timestamp.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/timestamp.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/datetime.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/datetime.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/date.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/date.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/boolean.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/boolean.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/foreign.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/foreign.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/unique.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/unique.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/primary.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/primary.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/index.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/index.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/column.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/column.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/constraint.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/constraints/constraint.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/operations.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/operations.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/default.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/datetime/default.xsd"/>
<uri name="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/queue_base.xsd" uri="file:/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/etc/queue_base.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

This list above was generated using Magento's CLI command:

```
php -f bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate urn_mappings.xml
```

Then converted into the format Eclipse expects.