# Magento 2 custom xml schema validation

Tags: magento2, xml, validation

This is a follow up of [Magento 2 xml validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/88242/146):
I understood how to map `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` in my IDE so I will get real time validation of my xmls.
But what if I have to create my own config file with it's own validation schema?
What value should I put for `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` ?

Right now I have this in `class.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<classes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="class.xsd">
   ....
</classes>
```

This works nicely, because `class.xsd` is in the same folder as my `class.xml`.
But I plan to make my module extensible and actually composed from multiple modules.
Now I use in the additional modules a relative path to the `class.xsd` file and this seams a bit wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<classes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Base/etc/umc/class.xsd">
   ....
</classes>
```

Obviously I cannot use `urn:magento:framework...` because my module is not in the framework, and I also cannot use `urn:magento:module...` because mine is not a core module. Or can I use the latter?
Or should I use a custom `urn`?
And (last one) if I use a custom `urn` will this be picked up automatically by the command `bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate` or should I dos something special?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `urn:magento:module:<Vendor_Module>:<path>` 
The command will work since it filters out urns that begin with `urn:magento`
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Developer/Console/Command/XmlCatalogGenerateCommand.php#L118