# Argument in DI.xml cannot resolve 'array' to a type definition for element 'argument'

Tags: magento2, xml, dependency-injection

Im new in magento 2. using DI.xml I'm creating a price adjustment. Weird to find that argument -> inside arguments is displayed in red with error cannot resolve 'array' to a type definition for element 'argument'.

any idea if it changed in the last release?.

[image]

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------
I realized  in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\etc\config.xsd is not defined. error says 'URI is not registered'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento2 2.0.0, it change xml schema validation. It using `URN schema validation`.

You can read more at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/XSD-XML-validation.html

You have to create my own config file with it's own validation schema?

You can read at [Magento 2 custom xml schema validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89609/magento-2-custom-xml-schema-validation)

In `di.xml` file, you need change to:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
....
<config>
```