# Magento 2 urn: no schema location

Tags: magento2, xml

when I open up a magento2 module.xml file, I see the location of the default module.xsd schema, if there is not a schema already set, defined like this :

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd
```

which resolves to the file :

```
vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd
```

My questions, although it may be stupid, is how does it know that

```
urn:magento: resolves to vendor/magento/
```

I am really interested about that.

Comment: See also [related question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88242/magento-2-xml-validation) about registering mapping in IDE.

Comment: saw that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the implementation of [\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver::getRealPath](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/Dom/UrnResolver.php), this particular method is responsible for URN conversion into real schema file path.