# Xml Element reference is not allowed here

Tags: magento2, xml, containers, theme-overriding

I am new to Magento & I am using **Magento version 2.1.7** in my **Windows 8.1** system with **Xampp** while creating a new module I am getting an error in my XML file located in the 
`app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout`

with below error message

`Element referenceContainer is not allowed here` for the reference Container

```
cannot resolve symbol 'content'
```

for the reference Container name

My Code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
        "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Funky\Hello\Block\Main"
                       template="blockContent.phtml"
                       name="funky_hello_HelloWorld"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please can some one tell me that what is the exact problem?

Comment: Well thats the separate error , But the reference content error will be solved by my below answer , also check in your template are you doing echo there ? Also have you clear the cache ? You need to put all files code like your .phtml file and your block as well

Comment: I have already checked my .phtml file I am echoing in my file. & by using your code it is now showing the below error
`can not resolve file page_configuration.xsd` I am using `phpstrom as an IDE` my cache is disabled & than also I have cleared the cache by cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your template with in module, you need to specify you module name `Vendor_Module`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
        "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Funky\Hello\Block\Main"
                       template="Vendor_Module::blockContent.phtml"
                       name="funky_hello_HelloWorld"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then, clear the cache and  check it.

Comment: check my latest update

Comment: check your controller works fine..  go you you `controller execute()`,  then command  your return statement  and write , `echo "Testing"` clear cache. Check it Now print your echo statement.

Comment: follow this answer  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88242/magento-2-xml-validation/88413#88413

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Funky\Hello\Block\Main" name="funky_hello_HelloWorld" template="blockContent.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also As per the coding standard it would be good to **`Remove extra space`** from **xml** tag and **page** tag.

Clear the cache and check